# using localStorage to keep a count

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

```
var nicWinsVsMac;

 if (tempresult === win) {
            wincount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem (playerName + 'wincount'));
            wincount += 1;
            localStorage.setItem(playerName + 'wincount', wincount);

        winsvsopponent = 'WinsVs' + opponent;
        winsvsopponent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(playerName + 'WinsVs' + opponent));
        winsvsopponent  += 1;
        console.log(winsvsopponent);
        localStorage.setItem(playerName + 'WinsVs' + opponent, 'winsVs' + opponent); 
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(nicWinsVsMac));    
    }
```

`playerName` and `opponent` are parameters passed in. In this case, `playerName = 'nic'` and `opponent = "Mac"`

My browser is giving me "unexpected token w" on the line where i parse out the `localStorage`. I cannot figure out what is going on. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is going on? You saved invalid JSON. Put a breakpoint on that line and inspect value.

Comment: where should i do that? not sure I follow sorry

Comment: Ok, at least do that: `console.log(localStorage.getItem(playerName + 'WinsVs' + opponent))` on line before error.

Comment: for some reason im just getting WinsVsMac   it should be nicWinsVsMac

Comment: let me try to put all the necessary parts on a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A8wun/ see if that makes more sense. thanks

Comment: This doens't make even a bit more sense.

Comment: no worries ill work on cleaning it up and try asking again later if i can't solve. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a separate localStorage variable for each attribute of the player. Why not store all the players attributes in a single object and then save that to localStorage.

For example, you can do the following:

```
var player = new Object();
player.name = 'Mac';
player.winCount = 3;
player.winAgainst = new Array();

localStorage.setItem(player.name, JSON.stringify(player));

var player1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(player.name));
console.log(player1.name + " has " + player1.winCount + " wins.");
```

This allows you to save all the player's attributes to a single localStorage variable making it much easier to read and write from.

In regards to the error you are recieving, I believe the issue with your code is that you are not using JSON.stringify in the call to setItem.